# How to capture params hash from posted JSON in sinatra app

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have this curl call:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name":"abc", "orgid":"12", "subject":"my subject"}' http://localhost:3000/mysinatraapp

post '/mysinatraapp' do
unless request.preferred_type.eql? 'text/html'
  # This is not really params hash. It will be a string like "{\"name\"=>\"abc\", \"orgid\"=>\"12\", \"subject\"=>\"my subject\"}"
    params = request.env["rack.input"].read 
    ...
    ...
    halt 400 if params.length == 0
end
  # This does not work
p "hi #{params['name']}"
end
```

`p "hi #{params['name']}"` fails because it's not a hash. How do I make it work?

My goal is to make posted json as `params` hash. so that I can use `params` as usual.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are actually passing a Ruby Hash instead of a JSON object.

Update your curl command to look like this:

```
-d '{"name":"abc","orgid":"12","subject":"my subject"}'
```

Then in your Sinatra action do like this:

```
params = JSON.parse(request.env["rack.input"].read)
```

Make sure you `require 'json'`

Comment: @Silvu it did not work.

`p request.env["rack.input"].read #=> "{\"name\"=>\"abc\", \"orgid\"=>\"12\", \"subject\"=>\"my subject\"}"

params = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(request.env["rack.input"].read)

p params #=> {} 
p params.class  #=> Hash
p params["name"] #=> nil`

Comment: Thats no-brainer. It was my bad. I corrected json.

Now `params = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(request.env["rack.input"].read)` gives me 

`{"{\"name\":\"abc\", \"orgid\":\"12\", \"subject\":\"sdfsdf\"}"=>nil}`

So I changed it to

`params = JSON.parse(Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(request.env["rack.input"].read).keys[0])`   that work perfect. Thanks.

Comment: In fact your most recent update `params = JSON.parse(request.env["rack.input"].read)` is better. I accepted it :)

Comment: @silvu there seem something weird going on in the approach. I have condition `unless request.preferred_type.eql? 'text/html'` to identify that the call is not coming from browser and in that condition, I execute `params = JSON.parse(request.env["rack.input"].read)` but when that condition is not met (i.e. call coming from browser) but `params` value become nil. So for browser based posting I lose `params`. However it works if I remove `params = JSON.parse(request.env["rack.input"].read)` , but isn't weird this statement only execute for non-browser calls . I am surprised what is going on.

Comment: try this in browser: `http://localhost:3000/mysinatraapp/?foo=bar` and see what `params` look like

Comment: That still keeps params nil.

Comment: what's the output of `request.preferred_type` on browser requests?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20497/discussion-between-jvk-and-slivu)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
require 'json'
params = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
```